# access a specified dimension of a N-D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, n-dimensional

I have a 3D array in MATLAB, with

```
size(myArray) = [1400 720 120]
```

the third dimension is 120 levels of depths : 0 - 5 - 10 .., and the 1400 and 720 is a geographic grid with values for each level of depth. I would like to get a specific layer, specified by an index in the third dimension (example depth = 5), in the form of a 2D matrix.

The squeeze function doesn't access the a specific number of the third dimension and my 2D matrix looks like:

```
B=squeeze(A(:,:,3));
size(B)
[1440 720]
```

How can I access the layer i.e: 5m of the [1440 720] matrix?

Comment: `B` is already a 2D matrix, which is what you want. Can you explain the problem better?

Comment: Yes I want to select the 2D matrix for a specified depth @Luis Mendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for something like this

```
zscale = 5;

depth = 5;
B = A(:,:,depth/zscale);
```

Comment: Perhaps modify `depth/zscale` to `floor(depth/zscale)` or `ceil(depth/zscale)` to avoid non-integral array indexing.